# Xcode 7: Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode7-beta6

After upgrade to **Xcode 7**, Xcode cannot run tests on simulator.

```
$ xcodebuild test -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme MyProject
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator9.0

xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project MyProject with scheme MyProject.
    Reason: Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
```

The issue is reproduced on [Travis CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4055#issuecomment-135633278) and Jenkins. It's worked fine when I run `xcodebuild test` on a local machine.

Answer (score 3):

I've gotten past this error by adding a flag like `-destination 'name=iPhone 6'`. It seems like xcodebuild used to pick a default destination but isn't doing that anymore. =|

I'm going to see if there is anything I can set in the build scheme to avoid hard coding a device.

Comment: It still fails after appending `-destination`

Comment: same error? what do you get for `xcodebuild -version`